# OpenWRT: Wired connection stop working when wireless enabled on RT-N13U

Tags: openwrt

I have an Asus RT-N13U and am running:  BARRIER BREAKER (14.07, r42625) on it. I used TFTP to install the openwrt-ramips-rt305x-rt-n13u-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin image onto it. Everything has been working fine until I enabled the wan. All of a sudden my wired connections don't work. Any ideas or pointers on where to look? This is my network config:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# cat /etc/config/network
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'
config globals 'globals'
    option ula_prefix 'xxxx:xxxx:4553::/48'
config interface 'lan'
    option ifname 'eth0.1'
    option force_link '1'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option ip6assign '60'
    option macaddr '00:0c:43:41:46:32'
    option ipaddr '192.168.7.1'
config interface 'wan'
    option ifname 'eth0.2'
    option proto 'dhcp'
    option macaddr '00:0c:43:xx:xx:xx'
config interface 'wan6'
    option ifname '@wan'
    option proto 'dhcpv6'
config switch
    option name 'rt305x'
    option reset '1'
    option enable_vlan '1'
config switch_vlan
    option device 'rt305x'
    option vlan '1'
    option ports '0 1 2 3 5  6t'
config switch_vlan
    option device 'rt305x'
    option vlan '2'
    option ports '4  6t'
```

Comment: Are you masking out your mac address or is it really set to `00:0c:43:xx:xx:xx`?

Comment: Masking out. It's not really set to `00:0c:43:xx:xx:xx`